# Javascript loop trough 2d Array

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, flask

so I am new to Flask and JS, so please excuse the probably silly question.. I've been working on a Flask app recently.
The problem I'm currently facing is that I want to output a 2d Array via a javascript in an HTML page.
The query and passing that trough to the HTML page ist not the problem, but I cannot find any way, to have some kind of variable that auto increments every iteration of the for loop.
The code for the JS part is as follows:

```
    {% for groupName in groupNames %}

    You are invited to the group "{{ groupNames[0][0]}}", created by "{{ groupNames[0][1]}}"

    {% endfor %}
```

The code works, but of course only outputs the first element.. I'm using the sqlite3 library for python.
The first 0 of booth elements would have to be incremented by one. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve the problem?

Cheers and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Javascript, but you should be able to output the iterator `groupName` with the following updated piece of code:

```
{% for groupName in groupNames %}

You are invited to the group "{{ groupName[0]}}", created by "{{ groupName[1]}}"

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more elaboration to @jonasdev's answer.

the built-in `for` loop when used like so:

```
{% for groupName in groupNames %}

    You are invited to the group "{{ groupName[0] }}", created by "{{ groupName[1] }}"

{% endfor %}
```

is getting `groupName[0]` then `groupName[1]` and so on... So that's why you only need to do

`You are invited to the group "{{ groupName[0] }}", created by "{{ groupName[1] }}"`

It's the same as saying:

```py
arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]

for item in arr:
    print(item)
    print(item[0])
    print(item[1])
```

in python.